# dynamic xpath at property file

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using *Java* and *Selenium* to write a test. I am willing to use a property file to save my web elements' Xpathes. My problem is that I have dynamic xpathes like

`//td[text()='name " + randomNumber + "']`

where the random number is an actual random number being created at run time.

so imagine that my random number this time is `123456`

so when I use:

`property.getProperty("the-Xpath-Name-In-Property-File")`

I want to have: `//td[text()='name 123456']`

but I get: `//td[text()='name " + randomNumber + "']`

Comment: Why not use only the part that is not changing? like //td[contains(text(), 'name')] or find alternative ways to identify the elements. Please add some specific examples if possible in the case you need more help.

Comment: @lauda the issue is that the whole name should be checked for many reasons

Comment: Then you will want to have a path that doesn't look for the text.  show us some of the HTML and perhaps we could make some suggestions.  just a couple of rows from this table should do.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the inspect tool in Chrome you get (example) random number 1179
//*[@id="gridview-1179-record-ext-record-100"]/td[3]/div

if you use FireFox FireBug then you don't get this dynamic ID:
/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div

Install FireBug.  Right click on the HTML object in question.  Move over to the FireBug panel and it usually defaults to HTML panel.  But if you are in CSS, Script and DOM, simply click to HTML. THEN right click AGAIN on the highlighted object and you will get a menu. "Copy XPath" will put the string into your mouse buffer.  Paste it into your code or a text editor

Comment: This random number always changes when I run the test, and i cannot use that tool kit to change the xpath everytime !!